# Problems getting monthly active users correctly (via Facebook Graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hey there!
I'm not able to fetch a reliable monthly active users number of my application. I tried it with FQL:

```
[...]
  $end_time = date('Y-m-d', time()-(60*60*24*2)); // Dont' know what is correct. Sometimes it's *2 sometimes it's working with *3
  $fql = $facebook->api(array(
                        "method"  => "fql.query",
                        "query"   => "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id='000000000' AND metric='application_active_users' 
       AND end_time=end_time_date('".$end_time."') 
       AND period=period('month')"
     ));
[...]
```

Looks like it's not possible to get a value up-to-the-minute. I want to get the same value as stated on my application page. But with this code it's different every day.

I also tried this solution:

```
  $fql = $facebook->api('/000000000/insights/application_active_users/month');
```

but as response I only get out dated values which are a few days old:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 000000000/insights/application_active_users/month
                    [name] => application_active_users
                    [period] => month
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 166345
                                    [end_time] => 2010-12-09T08:00:00+0000
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 167679
                                    [end_time] => 2010-12-10T08:00:00+0000
                                )
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 168983
                                    [end_time] => 2010-12-11T08:00:00+0000
                                )
                        )
                    [description] => Monthly Users who have engaged with your application or viewed your application (Unique Users)
                )
        )
    [paging] => Array
        (
            [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/000000000/insights/application_active_users/month?since=1291556506&until=1291815706
            [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/000000000/insights/application_active_users/month?since=1292074906&until=1292334106
        )
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook insights data is not available just-in-time. The insights graph will always display historic data only.

If you are interested for current `monthly_active_users` number look into the `applications` table with fql.

Comment: hey thx a lot! that helped me! I also found this: http://stuff24.de/blog/monthly-active-users-facebook-fql/